# Generar link desde outlook con una macro(vba) usando FollowHyperlink

Tags: macros, outlook

Tengo una macro que leer los correos y extra informacion y en base a esa informacion va a generar un link para responder a un servidor(en php) ya tengo esa parte pero no puedo generar los links desde la macro ya probe varios cosas y no logro que al momento que el correo recibe el mail automaticamente se abra el link
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Definitivamente no puede con followlink pero si encontre otro metodo que si me sirvio me refiero a ShellExecute 
Declare esta funcion

```
 Private Declare Function ShellExecute _
  Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "ShellExecuteA" ( _
  ByVal hWnd As Long, _
  ByVal Operation As String, _
  ByVal Filename As String, _
  Optional ByVal Parameters As String, _
  Optional ByVal Directory As String, _
  Optional ByVal WindowStyle As Long = vbMinimizedFocus _
  ) As Long
```

y lo llame de esta forma en mi metodo sbVBA_To_Open_Website_URL_FollowHypderlink

```
 Dim lSuccess As Long
lSuccess = ShellExecute(0, "Open", "www.google.com")
```